# Field extension and automorphism proof understanding.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $F\subseteq L $ is any field extension, $f(x) \in F[x]$, and $b_1,b_2,...b_r$ are distinct roots of $f(x)$ in L. Prove the following statements:

1) If $\sigma$ is an automorphism of L that leaves F fixed pointwise, then $\sigma_{|\{b_1,...,b_r\}}$ is a permutation of $\{b_1,...,b_r\}$

2)$\sigma \mapsto \sigma_{\{b_1,....,b_r\}}$ is a homomorphism of $Aut_F(L)$ into the group of permutations $Sym(\{b_1,....,b_r\})$

3) If L is a splitting field of f(x) , $L=F(b_1,....,b_r)$, then the homomorphism $\sigma \mapsto \sigma_{|\{b_1,....,b_r\}}$ is injective.

My thought:

1) Let $\sigma \in Aut_F(L)$ as defined, $\sigma $ sends a root of f(x) to another root and fixed others. It's trivial that $\sigma_{|\{b_1,...,b_r\}}$ is a permutation of the roots. (But I do not think my argument is good enough and I do not know how to fix either.)

I review for final, need a lot of help to organize the proof. Much appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Your thought regarding the solution to 1) is correct (and might be sufficient). Just remember why roots must be send to other roots: For $P \in K[X]$, $P(x)=0$, also $\sigma(P(x))=P(\sigma(x))=0$ (because $\sigma$ fixes the coefficients of $P$), therefore $\sigma(x)$ is a root of $P$.

For 2), there really is nothing to check, the restriction of a group action on an invariant subset is always a homomorphism, and 1) shows that the roots do form an invariant subset.

For 3), suppose $\phi$ to be an element in the kernel. This means that $\phi$ fixes each of the roots. But the splitting field is generated by the roots, therefore $\phi$ fixes all of $L$, therefore is the identity, i.e. the neutral element.

Comment: Thanks for respond. For 2) if I let $S=Aut_F(L)$ and $T= Sym (root)$, and $f: S\rightarrow T$. All I need is prove that f is homomorphism, right? That is if I pick $\sigma_1, \sigma_2\in S$ by defining, $f(\sigma_1+\sigma_2)=f(\sigma_1)+f(\sigma_2)$ same as product one, right? But only $\sigma_i \in Aut_F(L)$ work this way and it works only for Sym(root). Hence kernel f must be 0 (for part3), it is trivial as you said. How to put it in logic?